# How to inherit Basic Authentication credentials of the base page for the fetch API?

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication, fetch-api

I developed an https demo of a small web app on my local system. Now I deployed it behind Basic Authentication because it's not a public demo.

Now I encountered a problem: The app uses the Fetch API.

First I thought that `fetch()` inherits the Basic Authentication from the base page. But no! The fetch API seems do know nothing.

I know how to create the necessary Basic Authentication headers for fetch. It's not difficult. I have a different question:

**How can I inherit the Basic Authentication credentials of the base page for the fetch API?**

Rationale: It's a really small app and I don't want to complicate it with the configuration of a possible Basic Authentication. I also don't want to hardcode the credentials in the demo. I just want to inherit the credentials from the base page from which the fetches are originating.

Comment: I could let the server insert the credentials into the base page, like this for PHP: `/*JS code */ const credentials='<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']?>'` (not tested nor hardened against XSS). This would work but is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `credentials` property when initing the `fetch()`, it will inherit the page's Basic Authentication properties:

```
// can be omit, same-origin, or include
fetch( myURL, { credentials: 'same-origin' } ).then(...)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters for the full list of init parameters